# PHP code comment how to find it?

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have one website on OpenCart and in category view have comment on price . How can I find where is comment? I look in category .tpl file there no comment.I have no idea can you help me please to find it.
On this link can you see http://matrak.info/index.php?route=product/category&path=65
When I inspect code with chrome inspect I see this:

```
<div class="description">Описание..</div>
<div class="price">
    <!-- 72.00 лв. -->
</div></div>
```

In page code no have this comment.

```
<div class="description">Описание..</div>
<div class="price">72.00 лв.</div></div>
```

I can't understand there is the problem?

Comment: If you see something different in DOM inspector than what the original HTML code looked like - then most likely it has been manipulated by JavaScript ...

Answer (score 0):

The code for this is probably there in your controller file for this view. Find the category controller that generates data for the `category.tpl` file.

Comment: I looked  the controller file, and nothing. I think the problem is no in controller file. Maybe some .js file but I am a still beginner and can't find it.